# How to add a comment form to a page generated with $_GET

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website and basically, I made one page called "user.php" and I'm using $_GET to make it so it shows different profiles depending on what the URL is. Now I want to make a comment form so that anyone can post a comment on a specific user's profile. I've tried making the form but when I submit it, it reloads the page and I lose the data in the URL that allowed me to access someone's profile. So I was wondering is it possible to do what I want to do or do I have to use $_POST and make it create one different page for every single user?

To illustrate it here's an example of what I'm asking:

Index.php

```
<?php echo '<a href="user.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'_user='.$row['username'].'">'; ?>
```

User.php(?id=1_user=poop)

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment_form">
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If I click on the submit input, I get back to the URL User.php without any data sent to the server

Comment: What does *'Blabla with an input submit'* mean?

Comment: Please complete the `<form>` with all html (and php) :)

Comment: I edited, even though I don't think it changes anything since there isn't much. Adding the whole php page would make things confusing because it's so dirty

Comment: `?id=1_user=poop` doesn't look like a valid query string. If the query string is not being submitted with the form post, then you should set the `action` attribute to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a `&`.

Try Using:

```
echo '<a href="user.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] . '&' . '_user=' .$row['username']. '">';
```

Also remember:

> - GET requests can be cached
> - GET requests remain in the browser history
> - GET requests can be bookmarked
> - GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
> - GET requests have length restrictions
> - GET requests is only used to request data (not modify)

— from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the infos!

Comment: No Problem @Tchang

Answer (score 2):

You must seperate parameters on a Querystring with `&`

```
echo '<a href="user.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] . '&_user=' .$row['username']. '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add some hidden input in your form, so the parameters will be sent to the next page. For example

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$_GET['id'].'" >
```

Also, as mentionned by RiggsFolly answer, you should separate user id and user name, in the href.

Comment: Four spaces before line indicates code. Easier than all those backticks

Comment: And no need to use post and hidden inputs